# Json Deserialization parsing non valid Json object

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize A Json object retrived from Web API into list of strong type objects as follows :

WebClient wc = new WebClient();

```
        // Downloading & Deserializing the Json file
        var jsonMain = wc.DownloadString("http://api.flexianalysis.com/services/FlexiAnalysisService.svc/FlexiAnalysisNews?key=___&catagory=Forex");


        JObject token2 = JObject.Parse(jsonMain);

        List<News> listNews = new List<News>();

        foreach (var result in token2["d"])
        {
            news = new News();
            news.id = (string)result["ID"];
            news.Title = (string)result["Title"];
            news.Date = (string)result["PublishingDate"];
            news.Content = (string)result["News"];
            listNews.Add(news);
        }

        return View(listNews);
```

The problem is that I always get the result as 1 string, Because the parser does not parse a valid Json object. (I guess it get's to invalid character and can't get it parsed correctly)...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So you want a ***JSON*** parser to parse non-JSON ?

Comment: The content of `d` IS a valid JSON. I have just visualized it in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JArray results = JArray.Parse(token2["d"].ToString());`

Please try

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
// Downloading & Deserializing the Json file
var jsonMain = wc.DownloadString("http://api.flexianalysis.com/services/FlexiAnalysisService.svc/FlexiAnalysisNews?key=gZ_lhbJ_46ThmvEki2lF&catagory=Forex");


JObject token2 = JObject.Parse(jsonMain);
JArray results = JArray.Parse(token2["d"].ToString());

List<News> listNews = new List<News>();
foreach (var result in results)
{
    news = new News();
    news.id = (string)result["ID"];
    news.Title = (string)result["Title"];
    news.Date = (string)result["PublishingDate"];
    news.Content = (string)result["News"];
    listNews.Add(news);
}

return View(listNews);
```

Test:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>>`:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>>>(jsonMain);
List<News> news = root["d"].Select(result => new News()
{
   id = result["ID"] as string,
   Title = result["Title"] as string,
   Date = result["PublishingDate"] as string,
   Content = result["News"] as string
}).ToList();
return View(news);
```

Comment: This won't work. You are getting "Additional information: Error converting value ..." http://i.imgur.com/VwqrXlQ.png

Answer (score 0):

can be alternative

```
class News
{

    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PublishingDate")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("News")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

WebClient implements IDisposible interface. Using it in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is not bad.

```
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var jsonMain = wc.DownloadString("http://api.flexianalysis.com/services/FlexiAnalysisService.svc/FlexiAnalysisNews?key=gZ_lhbJ_46ThmvEki2lF&catagory=Forex");
            JObject token2 = JObject.Parse(jsonMain);
            string s = token2["d"].ToString();
            List<News> list = JArray.Parse(s).ToObject<List<News>>();
        }
```